# Supervisor auto restart after n process has done

Tags: laravel, process, queue, supervisord

Like laravel 9, I can run:

```
php artisan queue:work --max-jobs=100
```

But I'm using laravel 7, how can I run with supervisor.

Comment: What is your production environment?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? Maybe you should ask this in [sf]

Comment: You can always do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571052/have-supervisord-periodically-restart-child-processes) if you want all workers to be restarted periodically. Alternatively you can either upgrade your Laravel version (7 to 9 is not too hard) or transfer the source from 9 down to your code and use a custom command and worker class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.